# os.UserHomeDir() with sudo returns /root

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I'm running a CLI app, and using `os.UserHomeDir` func to save some files, it returns something like this: `/home/victor/.rit`, but when i run a command with sudo, it return: `/root/.rit/`, i want to get the same adress, with sudo or not, there's a way to do this with go?

Comment: That seems like the intended behavior. If you run your app with `sudo`, it runs with `root` privileges, and the home of `root` is `/root/`.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `$HOME` envvar? `sudo` doesn't seem to change it when I run `sudo echo $HOME`

Comment: @KevindeBerk that depends on how sudoers is configured and isn't universally true.

Comment: @KevindeBerk, $HOME is interpolated before the command is executed, so the shell executes something like `sudo echo /home/user`. See `strace -e execve sudo echo $HOME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Go program must run with `sudo`, you can find out the original user identity prior to sudo via:

```
username := os.Getenv("SUDO_USER")
```

then you can look up their user info:

```
import "os/user"

u, err := user.Lookup(username)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("user home:", u.HomeDir)
```

Comment: you may want to verify you are in `sudo` mode with a check like `os.Getuid() == 0`

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving correctly: `sudo` runs a command as a different user, `root`'s home directory is `/root`. So if you use `sudo` to run your program as root, the current user's home directory is `/root`. If you want a different directory, you should accept it as a CLI parameter, e.g. using the [`flag` package](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/).